# Maya Python Script Job Attribute Change

Tags: python, jobs, maya

I am trying to get one boolean attribute (A) to change another(B). The one to be controlled (B) already has a script job running it and so I can't create a set driven key, direct connection, or expression to control it, so I'm trying another script job, since running the script function by itself achieves the desired result. I just can't figure out how to tie that script to run to the attribute change (B) that I want to drive it by (A).

This is placed in a script node set to the open gui trigger (to load when maya opens as I understand it). [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hiac8.jpg).

What am I missing here?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def togglePicker(pickerAttr):

    cmds.setAttr(pickerAttr, not 0)
    

nameSpace = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0].rpartition(':')[0]

if len(nameSpace) > 0:
    pickerAttr = nameSpace + ':Main.picker'
    myPickerAttr = nameSpace + ':MoverMain_Cntrl.Picker'
else:
    pickerAttr = 'Main.picker'
    myPickerAttr = 'MoverMain_Cntrl.Picker'
    
 
cmds.scriptJob(attributeChange=[myPickerAttr,togglePicker])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work! (previously I had switched to the script node to MEL so I could test the mel command mentioned in the comments that did work, but I forgot to switch back to python when I realized the selection issue I also mentioned in the comments).

So here's what worked, where I know I'll have to manually change the namespace name in case the scene file name changes:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def togglePicker():
    cmds.setAttr(pickerAttr, not 0)

if cmds.namespace(exists='ExtremeBallRig_v008'):
    pickerAttr = 'ExtremeBallRig_v008:Main.picker'
    myPickerAttr = 'ExtremeBallRig_v008:MoverMain_Cntrl.Picker'
else:
    pickerAttr = 'Main.picker'
    myPickerAttr = 'MoverMain_Cntrl.Picker'
    
cmds.scriptJob(attributeChange=[myPickerAttr,togglePicker])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script node is executed every time when maya loads a scene, not when it is started, at least that's what the docs say. So every time you load a scene, a new scriptJob is created.

Your script should show an error message since the togglePicker() function is called without an argument, but it requires an argument. Even if it works, it will not work.. what you do at the moment is the following:
As soon as you turn on the `MoverMain_Cntrl.Picker` attribute, the `togglePicker()` function is called and turns it on, even if you turn it off. The `pickerAttr`variable is not used. So you should have a look at your program logic.

You can solve the agrument problem by using the partial function like this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

def togglePicker(pickerAttr):
    cmds.setAttr(pickerAttr, not 0)
    

nameSpace = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0].rpartition(':')[0]

if len(nameSpace) > 0:
    pickerAttr = nameSpace + ':Main.picker'
    myPickerAttr = nameSpace + ':MoverMain_Cntrl.Picker'
else:
    pickerAttr = 'Main.picker'
    myPickerAttr = 'MoverMain_Cntrl.Picker'
    
 
cmds.scriptJob(attributeChange=[myPickerAttr,partial(togglePicker, pickerAttr)])
```

Comment: Thanks @haggikrey I tried this in the scene and it didn't work, unfortunately.

I did get this mel script below to work, but it doesn't take into account namespaces and I don't know how to write the namespace appending logic in mel to make this work in case the rig is referenced in. Any ideas:
scriptJob -killWithScene -ac MoverMain_Cntrl.picker asPicker;

Comment: I think I know what might be happening, because my script needs a selection to determine the namespace, and if this runs when the scene opens, then there would be nothing selected yet. So I would think this fails altogether right at start up because there's nothing selected. So I guess I'm not sure how to make this script work with namespaces in general or if there's some way to do a wildcard kind of thing to grab everything with the same attribute with or without a namespace.